# Unable to start VM - Minikube

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I am trying to start the **minikube** using the `minikube start` command and this is the error i am getting. Even installed the latest version of `virtual box` but still it gives me this error.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

[image: image error]

Comment: upgrade (or install) the latest version of virtualbox

Comment: Checkout the issue on github: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3974
If you run ubuntu, try to update packages using sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Whats your current vbox version?

Comment: Did you try to run it with `--vm-driver` flag https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/virtualbox/ ? If this won't help, could you provide some steps to reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice of the error message.  Did you try installing `virtualbox-dkms` and the linux headers?

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-generic
```

Follow the instructions in the docs, if you aren't already:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recomend you to install newest version of [Minikbue](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/linux/) (currently it is 1.5.2) and [Kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux).

Second thing check if your machine is supporting virtualization. It can bo done via command `egrep -q 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo && echo yes || echo no`.

If it is `no` you have to:

- If you are running within a VM, your hypervisor does not allow nested virtualization. You will need to use the `None` (bare-metal) driver.
- If you are running on a physical machine, ensure that your BIOS has hardware virtualization enabled.

Minikube set `VirtualBox` as default driver, but you can use other. [Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/linux/) under `Hypervisor Setup` you might find that you can also use `KVM` or `None` as driver for Linux OS.

Solutions:

**1.** As Minikube output advised, try to install 
- `$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-generic`
- run `$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv`
- reinstall `VirtualBox`

**2.** If there is no `virtualization` option on your Laptop you can use `Minikube` with `--vm-driver=none` flag.

`$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none`

If you would use this option, you might need to specify `--cpus=X` and `--memory=XXXX` as default is requesting less resources.
Another think is that `none` driver provides limited isolation and may reduce system security and reliability. More info can be found [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/).

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) 

...

$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04
  Running on localhost (CPUs=2, Memory=7470MB, Disk=9749MB) ...
```

After successfull installation, don't forget to execute mentioned commands.

```
▪ sudo mv /home/<your_user>/.kube /home/<your_user>/.minikube $HOME
▪ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube
```